# how to add new library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I want add [this library](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) in Android Studio.

I added this

```
compile io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.1.1'
```

into `build.gradle` section .

But when sync android studio show me this error , please click on this link to see my error image

[image: https://image.ibb.co/mprfOQ/tyed.png]

How can i fix it? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They dont have 1.1.1 version, they have 1.1.2 version so use like this,

```
compile 'io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.1.2'
```

Check the version [here](https://bintray.com/luizgrp/maven/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) for more

Comment: I think developer didn't update the version in Wiki, I am not sure, but in bintray.com there is no version as 1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Click on error dialog and update your gradle because your library version and 
     gradle version is not matching.

please once update your gradle file the error will be resolved :)